# Редактирование местоположения контента, закрытого в тэг xmp

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Код, помещенный в тэг xmp на странице в браузере смещен к центру экрана, что может на это влиять и как этого можно избежать? Или стоит использовать иной тэг?

```html
<xmp>
  <div class="container"> контент сайта</div>
</xmp>
```

[image: Вид в браузере]

Comment: А какого результата ты хочешь добиться, используя этот тег?

Comment: Чтобы контент начинался слева

Comment: для этого никакой тег не нужен, а тег `xmp` не нужен ни для чего, он вообще устарел. Для настройки внешнего вида страницы принято использовать CSS.

Comment: тогда как мне отобразить пример кода на сайт?

Comment: Тег [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre).

Comment: Когда я его использую, та часть кода, которую я хочу продемонстрировать в неизменном виде, все равно почему-то читается как обычные тэги

Comment: Либо экранированируй 4 спец символа, либо используй `<textarea readonly>`

Comment: Понял, благодарю